# How to serialize a list of tuples to a JSON object

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a `List[(String, Any)]` in json4s and I'm using `write(lst)` to serialize JSON. How do I serialize this as a JSON object instead of a list **while preserving order**?

**Note:** I know that `write(lst.toMap)` will serialize to an object, but I want to preserve the order.

Comment: The fields of an object are not ordered in JSON (see http://json.org). Can you give more details why you want to do that?

Comment: Parser optimization. If I have a push parser (like SAX but for JSON), I can parse things more efficiently if the type discriminator (like `jsonClass`) comes first. MongoDB also does this internally with BSON so it can do typed queries faster.